# How to eliminate the padding in the nav menu from Refinery CMS?

Tags: css, refinerycms

There is currenlty padding on the left that is somehow added to the menu by refinery.

[image: padding]

When inspected the element for `header#header nav#menu` these are the CSS rules

```
header#header nav#menu {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px 6px;
}
```

The `<ul>` had no rules. And the item menus are floated as

```
header#header nav#menu ul li.first {
  float: left;
}

header#header nav#menu ul li.last {
  float: right;
}
```

So how can I push the first item menu into place? It seems to be floating as far left as possible, but its parent container may somehow be interfering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
header#header nav#menu ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

or

```
header#header nav#menu ul {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: The one that worked was header#header `nav#menu ul { padding-left: 0; }` which is weird since I could not see in firebug that there was any rules being applied to the `<ul>`.

Comment: I had same problem some time ago, and I think it's the browser, that automatically ads padding to ul lists.